# How to disable js/css cache?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

I try to develope a js script but I always have to clear the cache and wait about a minute until the changed file is loaded. Even emptying the folder /var/cache does not help.

Is it possible to disable js/css cache?

Comment: then you can comment in the layout xml file it won't be called.

Comment: How is this going to help, I need it to get called obviously.

Comment: are you using merged js/css? you probably shouldn't be when developing

Comment: No, I don't merge CSS/JS

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question, but if you refresh the page by `CTRL+Shift+R` the page will be reloaded ignoring cache which should solve your issue.

Comment: Nope, I already know this but it does not help. It takes about 30-60 seconds until the new file is loaded.